Is known plaintext attack on Zipcrypto still possible using BK94 algorithm?
In my recent tests both pkcrack and bkcrack are no longer working, maybe it's my PC.
I have zipped pkcrack.exe and chose compression level as store on both encrypted and unencrypted zip files and performed an attack but  got no solutions from both softwares and i thought maybe it's because of versions of my zippers, so changed up to several versions for each zipper software with no positive result.
The only thing i got from pkcrack is something like:

strange ... had a false hit

By the way, yes i have verified that the encrypted files are using the same compression parameters as the unencrypted.
If someone knows a working version, please help.
Here is BK94

BK94 stands for Eli Biham & Paul C. Kocher's 1994 A known plaintext attack on the PKZIP stream cipher.

Yes, Plaintext attack is always possible on Zip Crypto and now it turns out that only 6 plaintext bytes are required when working on CPU and 3 bytes on GPU.
In a few months, i think you will only need 1 byte plaintext since the discovery of using ciphertext to build internal state then use it as a mirror of $key3$ to get the actual internal state is in progress.
